# web.py sessions renew every reload under apache (cgi/wsgi)

Tags: python, apache, session, web.py

i have a web.py website that requires sessions;

the website's sessions work flawlessly when using web.py's built-in webserver, e.g.

```
./server.py
http://my.server:8080/cgi/server.py/
```

for production, i use apache2 with python as cgi.

when run in this configuration, the session is not reused as it should be;

instead, on every reload, i see 2 more session files (or db records) are added to the sessions dir / to the mysql table (depends how i configured it)

I have tried the following configurations, with same results:

- as apache cgi
- as apache mod_wsgi
- with sessions as disk storage
- with sessions as mysql data tables (1 to 3 records are inserted on each reload)
- web.py from 1 year ago
- newest web.py from source

i have a running installation of web.py & sessions on the same webserver, and it works, so i'm puzzled.

my setup is:

- ubuntu 12.04
- standard lamp (linux/apache/mysql)
- latest web.py 3.x

any clues on why sessions are not remembered / reused  under apache?

**Solution(s!)**

to solve this, i had to give value to cookie_path

```
web.config.session_parameters['cookie_path'] = '/'
```

also, note that the line above must come BEFORE session init code, i.e.

```
web.config.session_parameters['cookie_path'] = '/'
(...)
sess = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer=INIT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share your python code as well? I know I've had the same issue when the cookie path was not set.

Comment: as @victorkohler said, it was indeed the cookie path, that differs between apache and web.py's own server. i've set it to "/" and now it works.  (i'll recommend Aaron to write it in his wiki)